# Centering table of contents caption

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like to center the caption of my table of contents, so that it looks as follows:

```
                         Table of contents 

1.   Section                                              1
1.1  Subsection                                           3
1.2  Subsection                                           5
2    Section                                             11
```

Instead of

```
Table of contents 

1.   Section                                              1
1.1  Subsection                                           3
1.2  Subsection                                           5
2    Section                                             11
```

I've tried to `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centerline{Table of contents}}`, which worked fine for the apperance on the page.

But I'm using a book style where at the top of the page, on the *left* side, I want to have the name of the current chapter/section/whatsoever. But if I do the above, the text `Table of contents` is not on the left side, but in the middle (because of the `\centerline`).

Is there a way to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several package to modify the layout of contents. The simplest one for standard document classes may be `tocloft`. You can use:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
```

`\tableofcontents` is typesetted as `\chapter*`(for `book` and `report`) or `\section*`(for `article`). You can modify the layout of chapter(section) titles for table of contents. Thus `sectsty` or `titlesec` can be used for standard classes. You can use:

```
% \documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\centering}
\tableofcontents
\sectionfont{}
```

or

```
% \documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\centering\bfseries\Large}
\tableofcontents
\titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries\Large}
```

If you are using classes such as `memoir` and `koma-script`, there will be other command for this purpose. You'd better read the manual of these classes.

Comment: In one context, I had to add a `\hspace{0em}` after the last `\hfill`, otherwise the ToC title flushed to the right.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\chapter*{\centerline{\contentsname}}
\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
\@starttoc{toc}%
\makeatother

\chapter{foo}
bar

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

For me, the only workable solution was

```
\begin{center}
\tableofcontents
\end{center}
```